# select 3 tables in 3 array fields 1 mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

First of all my tables

I have stored my product's format/template data in the first table. A format/template can be used by many product.

```
Format meta table. Primary Key is format_id. (has some more other columns)
+-----------+-------+
| format_id | title |
+-----------+-------+
|     1     |  f.a  |
|     2     |  f.b  |
|     3     |  f.c  |
|     4     |  f.d  |
+-----------+-------+
```

In the second table I'm storing product data. Every product has a unique ID and uses only one unique Format/Template. This table contains data like product_price, product_quantity etc. Details of each Product is being saved in another table.

```
Product meta table. Primary Key is product_id. (has some more other columns)
+-----------+------------+-------+
| format_id | product_id | title |
+-----------+------------+-------+
|     1     |      1     |  p.a  |
|     1     |      2     |  p.b  |
|     1     |      3     |  p.c  |
|     1     |      4     |  p.d  |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

This is the final table where I'm saving Product's details. Here values are stored in cell_id => value pair.

```
Details table. No primary key. (has some more other columns)
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+
| format_id | product_id | cell_id | value |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+
|     1     |      1     |    1    |  d.a  |
|     1     |      1     |    2    |  d.b  |
|     1     |      1     |    3    |  d.c  |
|     1     |      1     |    4    |  d.d  |
+-----------+------------+---------+-------+
```

Now the result I want

```
$result => ['format_meta']  => ['format_id'] = 1
                            => ['title']     = f.a

           ['product_meta'] => ['format_id']  = 1
                            => ['product_id'] = 1
                            => ['title']      = p.a

           ['details']      => [0]   => ['format_id']  = 1
                                     => ['product_id'] = 1
                                     => ['cell_id']    = 1
                                     => ['value']      = d.a

                            => [1]   => ['format_id']  = 1
                                     => ['product_id'] = 1
                                     => ['cell_id']    = 2
                                     => ['value']      = d.b

                            => [2]   => ['format_id']  = 1
                                     => ['product_id'] = 1
                                     => ['cell_id']    = 3
                                     => ['value']      = d.c
```

I am totally clueless about how to do this.

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL joins?  Perhaps start by searching on that.

Comment: If I do it like this `(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cast(concat(d.cell_id, ':', d.cell_value) AS char) SEPARATOR ';')` for the details table (3rd). then I have do about 6-7 of this statement as I have to fetch data like `cell_id=>cell_value`, `cell_id=>cell_type` etc. Will that be a performance problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no matter how you craft your SQL statement, as far as I know and have seen, you will get a single line/array of values of all you columns you request; it will not come back formatted in that mutlidimensional array. That is something you will have to craft from the SQL response object you receive. To get all that column data you will need to craft your SQL statement with JOINS

```
SELECT f.title as formatTitle, p.*, d.cellid, d.value FROM Product as p JOIN  Format as f ON f.format_id = p.format_id JOIN Details as d ON p.product_id = d.product_id WHERE p.product_id = ?
```

After this you can create the above array from the results

Comment: If it is so then can you please tell me which one will be faster - 1st make 3 queries to the DB (it is not huge one about 10K rows in the 3rd table) or 2nd loop through the results in php

Comment: That is not a simple question and depends on your environment, which you shouldn't describe in detail here. If the database server has a pretty open connection to your apache server, has processing power (aka is not also used for other processes at your business) and this action is not performed constantly, then maybe using 3 separate queries will be fine. If it's not true, then you might be forced to make PHP do the heavy lifting. Again, not necessarily a simple answer.